# How to fix exception "NoSuchMethodError" in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, exception

I am new to spark, I use the following code to define spark object:

```
         SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("Java Spark basic example")
          .config("spark.master", "local")
          .getOrCreate();
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;)V
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:957)
at Spark.main(Spark.java:26)
```

It refers to line 26 where I wrote : .config("spark.master", "local").

Could you please explain why I am getting this error and how to correct it?

Comment: This would probably mean that you have a mismatch in versions of dependencies.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart the solution in How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError? did not work for me, that's why I created new question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yes you are right I changed my dependencies, and it works now...
Please write it as answer so I can mark it correct. And Thanks....

Comment: I continued working on the code, and I had another problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891658/how-to-fix-this-exception-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-in-spark
I will be very grateful if you can help....  @MarkRotteveel